# Find a word between 2 words and replace them

Tags: c#, string

How to find between 2 words and replace them into new string?
I wanna replace same.

for example given string :

```
string s = "word1-word2same-word3-word4";
same is = "word2";
```

What i wanna :

```
string s = "word1-word2word2-word3-word4";
```

But what if given string is:

```
string s = "word1same-word2-word3-word4";
same is -> word1;
```

What i wanna in this example:

```
string s = "word1word1-word2-word3-word4";
```

How to find what word is containing same? How to do it?

Comment: I think you need to describe your rules better.  Are the parentheses significant? How about the hyphen.  How do you define "a word"?  What does `same is -> tt(ss);` mean here?

Comment: If string contains same, needs to duplicate tt into firstGivenstring. So need to find before same's word

Comment: "*So need to find before same's word*" --- This is not a technical description of a problem

Comment: So you want to replace "same" with everything that comes before it up to a hyphen?  Like "abc-defsame" would be "abc-defdef"?

Comment: How do you denote "*find before same's word*", is it the dash ?

Comment: @juharr yes thats correct, i need to find what certain word containing same but there "-" always between words

Comment: "word1-word2same-word3-word4" = "word1-word2word2-word3-word4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following regular expression replacement is what you want

```
var input = "word1same-word2same-word3";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=^|-)([^-]*)same", "$1$1");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

would give you

> word1word1-word2word2-word3

So it will replace all the instances of "same" with whatever comes before it up to a hyphen or the beginning of the string.

Note that something like "whatsamesamesame" will give you a result of "whatsamesamewhatsamesame", basically it will only replace the last "same" after a hyphen or the beginning of the string.

Comment: Thanks thats what i am looking for! :), Anyways but if i wanna add "->" between found word and same word what should i have to do?

Comment: @00110001 yes sorry about that, my bad.

Comment: Just change the replacement to "$1->$1" and the output would be like "word1->word1-word2->word2-word3"

Comment: @juharr Yes, i found that. Thanks for everything. good answer.